# JAVA - getTime() from DB - always getting 01:00:00

Tags: sql, time, gettime

I have this code for selecting time from my database (SQLite):

```
String sql = "select cas from mytable where id = 'S222'";
Statement stmt2;
try {
        stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        while (rs.next()) {
           Time cas = rs.getTime("cas");
           System.out.println(cas.toString());     

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ...
    }
```

I am always getting value: 01:00:00 and in the database, there is a time set to 09:10:00
When I run this sql select statement in database by "execute command" I get right value. But when I run it from java application, it always prints 01:00:00. What is the problem? When I am selecting something else, not time, it is correct.

And I tried following select:

```
String sql = "select cas from mytable where id = 'S222' and cas = '09:10:00'";
```

And it also prints 01:00:00

Comment: Are you trying to get the database time? If yes, why do you select a cas column rom table1. It seems that this column stores the value of 01:00:00.

Comment: Try `getTimestamp("cas")` instead of `getTime("cas")`.

Comment: No, it is column in database and its type is Time. I have a table in database for courses in school. And each course has its day and time, when it starts. And I want to compare actual time with starting time of course. So that is why I am selecting column "cas". It is starting time of course. 

I tried Timestampe, the result is the same: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.009  
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/130298086/select.png

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
instead of:

```
Time cas = rs.getTime("cas");
```

I used:

```
String cas = rs.getString("cas");
```

and it works. TY